# How do I save a matrix of integers to a text file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, integer

I have a 2D matrix `myMatrix` of integers which I want to save its content to a text file. I did the following:

```
save myFile.txt myMatrix -ASCII
```

I get this message:

> Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
>       Variable 'myMatrix' not written to file. 
>   and nothing is written.

What to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To write myMatrix to myFile.txt:

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt', myMatrix);
```

To read the file into a new matrix:

```
newMatrix = dlmread('myFile.txt');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your matrix to double before using save.

```
>> myMatrix2 = double(myMatrix);
>> save myFile.txt myMatrix2 -ASCII
```

Comment: A) the first line gives me `Out of memory`. B) File `myFile.txt` has entries like `4.2280000e+03`, I would like `4228`

Comment: You can try using single instead of double. But I would reccomend that you use the method given by snakile, it is much better. An alternative would be to use the function fprintf, there you can specify the format of the output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [snakile's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546756/how-do-i-save-a-matrix-of-integers-to-a-text-file-in-matlab/3549881#3549881): to write myMatrix to myFile.txt, using CR/LF as line terminator ('pc'), otherwise, you should use LF ('unix'):

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt', myMatrix,'newline','pc');
```

To read the file into a new matrix:

```
newMatrix = dlmread('myFile.txt');
```