# How to keep formatting of a double array?

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix, floating-point, number-formatting

```
2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       4       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       4       3       3       0       3       3    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       4       4       9      44      31       4       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       4       0      31     277     531      29       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       4       7       0       3      10       0       3    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       4       3       0       0       5       0       1    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       3       1       1    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       3       1       2       1       1    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000  
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       4       0       4       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       5      27      21       6       0       3       3    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       3      31     274     316      25       1       1       1    2000    2000 
2000    2000    2000       0       0       4       5       4       6       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       3       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       4       0       3       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       3       3      64       6       0       3       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       3     473     374      30       9       1       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       4       3       4       2      10       3       2       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       2       1    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       3       0       3       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       4      18      34       9       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       6     251     344      17       2       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       8       2       3       5       0       3       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       4       0       2       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0    2000    2000
2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000    2000
```

Above is the table that I'm generating in MatLab currently, but when I try saving it, it just sticks it in one long string when i need to keep it in this formatting.  Also i need them to be comma separated in this format.

This is the snippet of code that I'm trying to use to save it.

```
new_fname = ['star_chip' '_' date '.txt'];
path1 = '\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\IDLtoMatlab\star_chips\';
fid = fopen([path1 new_fname], 'w');
fprintf(fid,'%d',star_block);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Just a note, notepad is notorious for not showing all of the formatting.  You might want to try to open it using wordpad instead to double check the formatting.

Comment: See my edit.  This looks correct when re copy/pasted back into word pad.

Comment: Is there a way to read in a row at a time and create a new matrix this way?  It appear that this is the way that it is being done in the file that I'm trying to replicate which was done in IDL.

Comment: @BenB.: So the delimiters you are after are comma followed by a <kbd>TAB</kbd> or is it comma followed by spaces?

Comment: It's not necessarily spaces inbetween commas. There are 5 places for characters inbetween each comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possiblity for you to play with.  This doesn't get the commas in there, I will take a stab at getting that to work later if you really want them.

This is assuming the matrix you want to save is named `A` and `fid` is the file id for the file you've opened to write to.

```
fid = fopen('filename path here', 'w');
for n = 1:size(A,1)
    fprintf(fid, '%5d', A(n,:))
    fprintf(fid, '\r\n')
end
```

The `%5d'` in the `fprintf` command specifies a field width of 5 for a data type of signed integer.  You could replace the `d` with an `i` or `u` if you really wanted to.  `d` and `i` are the same though.  `u` is just unsigned.  There are tons of other modifiers you could use if you wanted to, just take a look at the function in the help file.

Also the second `fprintf` line is to be used when viewing in notepad.  It adds a carriage return and a newline so it bumps the next row down and does so within notepad (which required the carriage return) as well.

Hope that helps some!

---

A somewhat messy (as in another loop, eww =P ) way to get the comma in that I thought of.

```
fid = fopen('filename path here', 'w');
for n = 1:size(A,1)
    for m = 1:size(A,2)
        fprintf(fid, '%5d', A(n,m));
        fprintf(fid, ',');
    end
    fprintf(fid, '\r\n');
end
```

I'm not a big fan of using this route but it does get the job done.  If `A` is really large you're effectively going through every element of it here.

---

This reflects the comment left by Thor:

```
fid = fopen('filename path here', 'w');
for n = 1:size(A,1)
    for m = 1:size(A,2)
        fprintf(fid, '%5d,', A(n,m));
    end
    fprintf(fid, '\r\n');
end
```

Comment: Loops may be gross in MatLab but this one works perfectly (and waiting 10sec for it to complete isn't TOO bad =P)  haha, thanks a ton again Ben!

Comment: You don't need the second `fprintf`, put the comma in with the integer conversion, i.e. `'%5d,`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dlmwrite` function instead, if you want it stored as an ASCII table use:

```
dlmwrite(new_fname, int64(star_block), '\t')
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the numbers in the notation i have above and not convert them into scientific notation?

Comment: Did a google search and ran into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546756/how-do-i-save-a-matrix-of-integers-to-a-text-file-in-matlab), which convinced me that `dlmwrite` is a better choice.

Comment: I added what I want the output to look like in a .txt file when opened in notepad.

Comment: AFAIK Matlab doesn't have direct support for writing files this way. The easiest way is probably post processing with `sed` if you have it available. It would be possible to do it within Matlab with a double `for` loop, something along the lines of: `[m, n] = size(star_block); for i=1:m; for j=1:n; fprintf ...`.

Comment: See my comment under the question.  It appears that I need to read in the file row to row.  There are 78 values per row and there are 5 characer spaces inbetween the commas separating the values.  and at the beginning of each row there is a single space.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thor,  I didn't notice that the files were being read via row until this morning after more scrutiny, and that was a pretty important detail that was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into

```
dlmwrite('output.txt', yourMatrix);
```

and it's accomplice:

```
yourMatrix = dlmread('input.txt')
```

Naturally, there is a bunch more options you might need. Type `help dlmwrite` or `doc dlmwrite` for more information.